# How to pass initial values to Field Array and handle form values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have react select using sortable container the problem I am having is that the values that are extracted is like this

```
{
  "fruits": [
    {
      "fruitName": {
        "id": 3,
        "value": "vanilla",
        "label": "Vanilla"
      }
    },
    {
      "fruitName": {
        "id": 1,
        "value": "chocolate",
        "label": "Chocolate"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

if you notice that `fruitName` is duplicated each time I select an option despite that I don't need it I just want it like a list like this

```
{
  "fruits": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "value": "vanilla",
      "label": "Vanilla"
     },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "chocolate",
      "label": "Chocolate"
    }
  ]
}
```

and if I remove `fruitName` field from field name it doesn't work correctly also how to pass initial values to this if I already have selected list values of fruits

```
import React from "react";
    import Styles from "./Styles";
    // import { render } from "react-dom";
    import { Form, Field } from "react-final-form";
    import arrayMutators from "final-form-arrays";
    import { FieldArray } from "react-final-form-arrays";
    import {
      SortableContainer,
      SortableElement,
      SortableHandle,
    } from "react-sortable-hoc";
    import Select from "react-select";
    
    const options = [
      { id: 1, value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
      { id:2, value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
      { id:3, value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" },
    ];
    const DragHandle = SortableHandle(() => (
      <span style={{ cursor: "move" }}>Drag</span>
    ));
    
    const SortableItem = SortableElement(({ name, fields, value }) => (
      <li>
        <DragHandle />
        <Field name={`${name}.fruittName`}>
          {({ input }) => (
            <Select options={options} placeholder="Select Location" {...input} />
          )}
        </Field>
        <span onClick={() => fields.remove(value)} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
          Remove
        </span>
      </li>
    ));
    
    const SortableList = SortableContainer(({ items }) => {
      return (
        <ul>
          {items.map((name, index) => (
            <SortableItem
              key={`item-${index}`}
              index={index}
              value={index}
              name={name}
              fields={items}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    });
    
    const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    
    const onSubmit = async (values) => {
      await sleep(300);
      window.alert(JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2));
    };
    
    const sortEnd =
      (move) =>
      ({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {
        move(oldIndex, newIndex);
      };
    const Home = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <Styles>
            <h1>React Final Form - Array Fields</h1>
            <a href="https://github.com/erikras/react-final-form#-react-final-form">
              Read Docs
            </a>
            <Form
              onSubmit={onSubmit}
              mutators={{
                ...arrayMutators,
              }}
              render={({
                handleSubmit,
                form: {
                  mutators: { push, pop },
                },
                pristine,
                reset,
                submitting,
                values,
              }) => {
                return (
                  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div>
                      <label>Company</label>
                      <Field name="company" component="input" />
                    </div>
    
                    <div className="buttons">
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => push("fruits", undefined)}
                      >
                        Add Customer
                      </button>
                      <button type="button" onClick={() => pop("fruits")}>
                        Remove Customer
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <FieldArray name="fruits">
                      {({ fields }) => (
                        <SortableList
                          useDragHandle={true}
                          items={fields}
                          onSortEnd={sortEnd(fields.move)}
                        />
                      )}
                    </FieldArray> 
                    <div className="buttons">
                      <button type="submit" disabled={submitting || pristine}>
                        Submit
                      </button>
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={reset}
                        disabled={submitting || pristine}
                      >
                        Reset
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2)}</pre>
                  </form>
                );
              }}
            />
          </Styles>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help your answer,

If you don't want to repeat an object/value you have to just filter out it.

Below is an example,

```
fruits = [
    {id: 1, name:'Mango'},
    {id: 2, name:'Apple'},
    {id: 3, name:'Orange'}
]
```

If your selected id is 2, So you want every other value except 2,

```
let selectedId = 2;
let filteredFruitArray = fruits.filter((fruit) => fruit.id !== selectedId);
console.log(filteredFruitArray); //{id: 1, name:'Mango'}{id: 3, name:'Orange'}
```